# unable to fetch opening_hours key from goole place details APi

Tags: node.js, google-maps-api-3

I am using node-googleplaces npm package in node.js. I want to fetch opening_hours key in response.
Using this Api
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&key=YOUR_API_KEY
But unable to receive this parameter in response.

Comment: What does the JSON response look like? What does your code that gets the details from that response look like?

Comment: @duncan I think issue is with country level restriction maybe. because when I try KFC America address to get opening_hours there was no key of opening_hour. but when I used Australia KFC address I was able to get opening_hour key with same API both times.

Comment: Maybe they just don't know the opening hours for all the KFCs

Comment: @duncan yes. you are right. that's because of country level restriction.